# Transcode any video to mp4 with max. 800 width or max. 800 height + watermark

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, h.264, watermark, transcode

I need a ffmpeg command that works with every video (with audio) format / type to encode it to h264 mp4. The output may have a maximum width of 800px and a maximum height of 800px. It would also be necesary to add a watermark in to bottom right corner... Is there a way to get all those things done with a single command line? Even if it's WMV, MOV, 3gp and whatever filetype is beeing used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i video -i watermark
       -filter_complex "[0]scale=min(800,iw):min(800,ih):force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,
                           scale=2*trunc(iw/2):2*trunc(ih/2)[v];
                        [v][1]overlay=x=W-w-10:y=H-h-10" output.mp4
```

The first scale filter fits the video to within a 800x800 canvas but proportionally. The 2nd scale filter makes sure that the video has even dimensions - required for standard H264 playback compatibility.

The image overlay is overlaid at bottom-right corner, offset by 10 pixels from both edges.

Comment: It says: W[Parsed_scale_0 @ 0x31c22c0] Invalid size 'max(800'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x31bc460] Error initializing filter 'scale' with args 'max(800' I also tried min and max with no result. Maybe the clip ist too "small" (480x270)? @Gyan

Comment: In your shell, looks like you need to escape the commas, so `min(800,iw)` should become `min(800\,iw)`. And it should be min, not max.

Comment: Still doesn't work :( @Gyan [Parsed_scale_1 @ 0x3fcc200] [Eval @ 0x7ffffa1863d0] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'w)'
Error when evaluating the expression '2*trunc(ih/w)'.
Maybe the expression for out_w:'2*trunc(iw/2)' or for out_h:'2*trunc(ih/w)' is self-referencing.
[Parsed_scale_1 @ 0x3fcc200] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_scale_1
Error configuring complex filters.
Invalid argument

Comment: Worked - thanks. I also needed to add -strict -2 because one codec seemed to be experimental - but now it works pretty well! Thank you for your great help @Gyan.

Comment: Your ffmpeg build appears to be >3 years old. Upgrade.